# Can't see files in mounted drive, but space is occupied

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ntfs

I was trying to make my external NTFS drive writable on macOS BigSur and followed a post, so I wrote the following commands:

```
sudo umount /Volumes/Untitled
sudo mkdir /Volumes/Mount
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/Mount
open /Volumes/Mount
```

After this, my files got mounted in the Mount folder but after a while, the folder disappeared and now if I access my Untitled drive, it shows the correct space, but can't see files anymore.

How can I fix it? I can't lose my files.

If I write `diskutil list`, I get this

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS                         1.0 TB     disk3s1
```

How can I recover the previous state where I can see my files? I'll just move them to another drive and format this one to a different file system.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. 1) I'd recommend that you check your drive with a Windows computer, your drive's contents may be damaged (by default, macOS reads NTFS drives, but can't write to them. The command you used activates read-write access, which is undocumented and unsupported. If you need to write to your NTFS drive, I would strongly recommend that you use Paragon NTFS or some other software instead, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130414/ntfs-drivers-on-mac for more information). 2) Is there a reason for using NTFS instead of APFS?

Comment: Also, "followed a post" -> can you please add/share the link to this post?

Comment: checked with windows... and it won't open. Checked with parrot linux and still won't open... how can i save it?

It just happened to be nfts cause the first time i used it on windows and i didn't worry much about it... I don't have the link to the post cause i have been googling a lot and it's lost in the history... how can i save my files? :(

Comment: I tried to access the disk with daisydisk and it gives me 900gb of hidden space... that is the amount of the files that i have. so it's like the files are there but for some reason are not visible... how can i recover them?

Comment: just tried to access from windows to do a chkdsk but it says can't access disk so can't do disk cleaning

Comment: with the volume mounted on your Mac open a terminal. type _ls -al /Volumes/Mount_ and hit return. please post the output here.

Comment: won't show mount anymore... it says ls: /Volumes/Mount: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard. Just had to run it, took a while but then it fixed my drive. I could access and save all my files!!!! saved 1tb of pics

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).